# Java splash screen not working when using a shortcut

Tags: java, shortcut, splash-screen

I have created an exe from my jar file with Launch4j. I have a splash screen in png which is loaded executing with the parameter -Splash:logo.png

When I execute the exe file, it works properly. But if I execute the program from a shortcut, it doesn't work (I mean the splash image, the rest of the program works ok).

Why does this happen? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: you add the parameter to your exe? if so, the shortcut would need this parameter too

Comment: The parameter is needed for the jar, and that's configured at Lauch4j to be inside the exe. So I just have to double-clic the exe and it works, without having to write the parameter again. Since a shortcut just calls the executable, I don't understand why it doesn't show up then

Comment: simply because the shortcut calls the exe directly, without its arguments defined. You must define the argument in the shortcut too :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set your working directory in the shortcut.**

One of the shortcut properties should say "Start in" or "Working directory".  Make sure that you have this set to the same directory that the shortcut is in.  When you double-click on the exe to start it, this happens automatically.  When you create a shortcut, this could be set to anything.

The problem here isn't that the shortcut is losing the parameter.  This is impossible since it's compiled into the exe file.  The problem here is that the application cannot find logo.png, which it is expecting to be in a subfolder of the working directory.

Comment: Yes! That was the problem. Instead of pointing to the installation folder, it was pointing to the installation folder/bin/. I don't know why, I'll investigate and try to fix it. Thanks for your help!